# How To Move Test Explorer Window To Vertical Bar In Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visualstudio

Does anyone know how to move the Test Explorer window to the "small vertical bar" in MS Visual Studio pls ?

I am using MS Visual Studio 2015.

I have attached a screen shot.[image]

I have checked the Microsoft Website & did a Google search. But no helpful information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdee4yb6.aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Just drag the tab (the bit that has the words "Test explorer") towards the middle of the window. As you drag it, expect to see a wireframe of possible locations and drag the tab to the wanted place in that wireframe. Afterwards, you may need to click on the "pin" in the tab (so it toggles between horizontal and vertical) so that the panel collapses into the vertical bar and just its name is shown. Click the name to open the panel and click the pin again and then the panel shoudl stay open at the left side of the window.